# How to enable autominify of .js and .css files in PHP storm 10.0.3?

Tags: phpstorm, minify

I want to see CSS and JS files normaly when editing them. But when I save/upload them to server I want them to be *minified*. Is there a plugin/setting that does this in the current version of **PHPstorm**?

Comment: Lots of tools that do that, but not PhpStorm by iteself. You may want to look at compass/gulp tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHPStorm doesn't have any built-in functions for minifying files... But there are plenty of different tools on the web - plus you can create your own batch files for this.
I can suggest using Grunt [grunt-contrib-uglify](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify) and [grunt-contrib-cssmin](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-cssmin) tasks, for example . Both tasks support merging and minifying files. You can run the tasks using Grunt console. Or, you can use [YUI Compressor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yui) and set it up as a file watcher (https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/minifying-javascript.html, https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/minifying-css.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can add css, or js File Watcher in PhpStorm, see their docs, using uglify or yuicompressor. All configurable from the IDE

After proper setup, your .css and .js files will be minified locally( PhpStorm shows them nicely together in the left sidebar where your files are). Each time you change your original css or js file, minified versions will be autogenerated.

When uploading to the server, you just need to upload automatically minified versions.

Very convenient. I use it for non-Symfony projects ( in symfony i use assetic for minification and combining assets into one file)